# JES: I/O operation on closed file error

Tags: python, jes

```
def calculateGrades():
  file = open(pickAFile(), "rt")
  highestGrade(file)
  lowestGrade(file)

def highestGrade (file): 
  lines= file.readlines()
  file.close   
  len_lines_file = len(lines) 
  lines = lines[1:len_lines_file]

  highest_Grade = 0.0 
  parts = lines[0].split(",")
  highest_Grade = int(parts[2]) 
  for line in lines:
    parts = line.split(",")
    if int(parts[2]) > highest_Grade:
      highest_Grade = int(parts[2])
def lowestGrade(file):
  open(file(, "rt")
  lines= file.readlines()
  file.close()
  len_lines_file = len(lines) 
  lines = lines[1:len_lines_file]

  lowest_Grade = 0.0
  parts = lines[0].split(",")
  lowest_Grade = int(parts[2]) 
  for line in lines:
    parts = line.split(",")
    if int(parts[2]) < lowest_Grade:
      lowest_Grade = int(parts[2])
  print lowest_Grade
calculateGrade()
```

calculateGrade() is what my professor calls the "overlord" function. I am trying to run the file that is pulled in the main function in both the LowestGrade and the highestGrade function but it keeps keeps giving me O/I error and I am not sure what to do.

Comment: your code is incomplete and contains syntax errors

Comment: Error 1: `open(file(, "rt")`. Error 2: `file.close` ...Also, I recommend using `with / as` syntax for open files, as this prevents the need to close files: http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Comment: add example of input, what `pickAFile` is?

Comment: I accidentally put the parenthesis when coping it here, that is already fixed. I'm not sure how to go from one function to the next. I tried,       
   with open(pickAFile(),"rt") as file: and got rid of the file.close but the with /as is a syntax error now

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the error you have would happen when you try to run `lowestGrade()` immediately after running `highestGrade()`. This happens because you have closed the file in `highestGrade()`, but do not open it correctly in `lowestGrade()`: the first line in your definition of `lowestGrade()` should be something like `file = open(pickAFile(), "rt")`.

Often, it is preferable to open files using a `with` block, e.g.:

```
with open(pickAFile(), "rt") as file:
    lines= file.readlines()
### file.close() is automatically called by Python at the end of the with block
```

So one option is to remove the open/close lines from the `highestGrade` and `lowestGrade` functions, and do it outside, say

```
def calculateGrades():
  with open(pickAFile(), "rt") as file:
    highestGrade(file)
    lowestGrade(file)
```

However, you may want to consider using `parts` as the argument to `lowestGrade` and `highestGrade`, and compute it outside the function:

```
def calculateGrades():
  with open(pickAFile(), "rt") as file:
    lines= file.readlines()
  len_lines_file = len(lines) 
  lines = lines[1:len_lines_file]
  parts = lines[0].split(",")
  highestGrade(parts)
  lowestGrade(parts)
```

and truncating the code in `highestGrade` and `lowestGrade` as necessary.

Comment: It is still giving me an error just a syntax error, I tried both ways

Comment: That's because your code is incomplete and contains syntax errors, as has been pointed out in your question.

Comment: no its giving me a synax error at  with open(pickAFile(),"rt") as file: